# Understanding this use of a dictionary/list in a rock paper scissors program?

Tags: python

I do not understand what this is exactly saying: `a.lower() == x and b.lower() == rules[x]:`

```
rules = {'rock':'scissors', 'scissors':'paper', 'paper':'rock'}

def checkResult(a, b):
    if a.lower() == b.lower():
        return 'Draw'
    for x in rules:
        if a.lower() == x and b.lower() == rules[x]:
            return 'Player one wins'
    else:
        return 'Player two wins'

def plyerInputCheck(player):
    text = "Player {}, type your choice (Rock, Scissors, Paper): ".format(player)
    playerChoice = input(text)
    while playerChoice.lower() not in rules:
        print("Wrong input, try again!")
        playerChoice = input(text)
    return playerChoice

while True:
    a = plyerInputCheck("One")
    b = plyerInputCheck("Two")
    print(checkResult(a, b))
    answer = input("Play again?")
    if answer.lower() in ("n", "no"):
        break
```

I get the a.lower() == x part, but what exactly is the b.lower() == rules[x], specifically what `rules[x]`is saying?

Comment: You must learn how to use dictionaries. This is really basic knowledge, and SO is not a suitable place for such questions.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's have a detailled look.

```
for x in rules:
```

What are all the `x` in `rules` ? You have `x = "rock"`, `x = "scissors"` and `x = "papers"`.

`rules` is a `dict`, so there are keys and values in it. For example, it has the value `"scissors"` attached to the key `"rock"`, so `rules["rock"] == "scissors"`.

```
    if a.lower() == x and b.lower() == rules[x]:
        return 'Player one wins'
```

Therefore, we are here checking if the player `a` gets a key with as value what the player `b` have (in our example, it would be `a` gets `"rock"` and `b` gets `"scissors"`.

If so, player `a` wins.

---

You really need to learn more about dictionaries though, because this is more than essential. Check on [this](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/how-to-use-dictionaries-in-python/) to learn basics of `dict` objects.

Comment: Yeah I should brush up on that. I get it now, it just flew right over my head and I couldn't think logically about it, but you clarified it. Thank you.